# drop down changes from other drop down with calculation. Jscript / Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a Jscript Query.

I have done a bit of reading and found out that AJAX is just a side server for a lfash script that can be used on Linux with php. (please correct me if I have interperated that wrong)

I have no knowledge on how scripts work so this is new, I have tried a couple of different tries but no luck.

I have one drop down box (Box1) (populated from Database) 
I have another box (Box2) for a calculation to insert into my database for other uses on ohter parts of hte site.

I need the Box2 to change the figure when someone changes Box1 dropdown before hitting the submit button.

I think because I have the calcualtion this is getting me stuck... Code is as below... Can someone please help me figure out (I think I need some form of Script to do this.) the answer...

Box1

```
<td><p>selection 1</p>
         <select id="t1_type" name="t1_type">

<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t2` ORDER BY t2_value");
while($valuerow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.$valuerow['t2_name'].'">'.$valuerow['t2_name'].'</option>'; } ?>
```

Box2

```
    <input name="t1_value" id="t1_value" value="
    <?php 
      $var1 = $row_value['t2_value']; 
      $var2 = $row_dropdown['t1_number']; 
      $total = round ($var2 *  $var1); 
      echo "" . $total . ""; 
    ?>" />
```

I hope this is all the code you need, (Let me know if more required)

What it needs to do is show new calculation whenever someone changes the box1 option BEFORE the submit button is clicked, so it submits the correct calculation to the database for future use.

I think it would need pretty much "t2_value" from box2 to change when ever "t2_name changed from box1.

And once again the best link to learn about the solution. (Learnt about Joins now from my last question!! Almost a intermediate user. ;-)  )

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

I saw that your second box was a textbox I believe, if thats the problem then you should do something like this

```
<select id="t1_type" name="t1_type" onchange="change(this);">
   <?php 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t2` ORDER BY t2_value");
      while($valuerow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo '<option value="'.$valuerow['t2_name'].'">'.$valuerow['t2_name'].'</option>';
      } 
   ?>
</select>
```

This defines your `<select>` box like you did in your question.
Add an `onChange` event into your first `<select>` and then create a function to handle to `onChange` event. An onChange event fires whenever the user changes the item in the `<select>` element.

Javascript :

( put this part of the code above the `</head>` )

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function change(element)
    {
     // do here whatever you want
     // you can change the value of the <input> box with :
     // document.getElementById(element.id).value = your_value
     // If you want to see if this part works, then try adding this :
     // alert("It works!");
     // If you want to get the text of the item which has been selected in Box1 use :
     // $("#t1_type option:selected").text();

    }
</script>
```

**Note: because PHP is server side, you can't update your Box2 dynamically without a page refresh, Javascript however is Client Side and CAN do this.**

Note : the `$("#t1_type option:selected").text();` code requires you to include the jQuery library into your script. Be sure to convert this variable to a float, int or double if you want to calculate with it, else the outcome will give NaN (Not a Number)

Tutorial on including jQuery Libary :
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

If you're new to JavaScript, you should try some tutorials. The ones at w3Schools.com helpt me alot, but some people say they're not always correct, but anyhow, read some stuff about Javascript to actually know what you are doing, instead of copypasting code :)

Comment: Thanks Looks good, But still confused. Have read through W3 (but they dont really explain the different elements of Jscript just show ideas, and played around with your code, but cant seem to figure it out still. I am guessing that where you say "Calculate your outcome here" that means using "var value_select_1 = $('#select_1').val();" type scenerio like I did in the PHP with two $VAR ?? I will keep looking and playing to see if I can learn this new stuff for this problem, but if you have any further help I will be appreciative of your help. :-)

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want a user to choose an option out of the first `<select>` box and then put a value in Box2 depending on the value of the selected option in Box1? Your code is a little vague to me, so I'm trying to help as good as I can :)

Comment: @Rocsha I editted the code as I saw fit for your problem, if you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi Harmen, YOur help is appreciated. :-) What I want it to do is. A User chooses a option out of the first select box. and the second one calulates the new outcome. EXAMPLE: select box 1: 1, 2, 3, 4. Second box (not editable by user) will calculate a new figure based on what was selected in the first box. This will in turn save the new figure to the database once submit is clicked. I have attempted the above and it did the "alert" but I couldnt get it to place the new calculated figure in box 2. I can email the complete code to you if that would help. Once again, Thanks for your help so far.